# Packagist skipped branch ending in -dev, complaining that is does not end in -dev

Tags: composer-php, packagist

Here's the error I get from packagist when updating a pacakge:

> Importing branch 2.x-dev (dev-2.x-dev)
>
> Skipped branch 2.x-dev, Invalid
>
> package information:  extra.branch-alias.dev-master : the target branch (2.x) must end in -dev

The branch is named "2.x" - Can anyone explain what is wrong with the branch name?

I've also tried naming branches "2.x-dev" and "2.0"

Here's the package: https://packagist.org/packages/messageagency/force.com-toolkit-for-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias defined in [`composer.json`](https://github.com/messageagency/Forcecom-Toolkit-for-PHP/blob/d7ed963d7220208ce414be3015a4050ca4e542ff/composer.json#L12) is incorrect - it must end with `-dev`, so you should use something like `"dev-master": "2.x-dev"` instead of `"dev-master": "2.x"`.

See documentation of branch aliases: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#branch-alias